# How do i send mails using nodemailer without getting error 500

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

i get error code 500 while trying to send mail with nodemailer. i am Firebase functions and express.
Take a look at my code and tell me what i'm not doing right.

```
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.login;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.pass;
admin.initializeApp();

app.post('/visitor/contact', (req, res, next) => {
    return cors()(req, res, () => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        //transporter is a way to send your emails
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: gmailEmail,
                pass: gmailPassword
            }
        });

        // setup email data with unicode symbols
        //this is how your email are going to look like
        const mailOptions = {
            from: gmailEmail,
            to: req.body.email,
            subject: 'Full stack developer',
            html: `<h1 style="color:blue;">Welcome ${req.body.firstName}</h1>
                <p style="font-size:25px;">Thank you very much for contacting me. i hope you are having a great time where ever you may be.</p>
                <p style="font-size:25px;">I am a full stack developer by training and i am available at the moment for a MEAN stack job That will challenge me to be better.</p>
                <p style="font-size:23px;">Thanks ${req.body.firstName}</p>`
    };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        next();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not making any call to res.send() or res.json() so the server doesn't return a response. So I believe the next variable might be undefined so you might want to test it for nullish values before calling it